# How to retrieve text from an input

Tags: javascript

I have an edit button, on click every td in the row will become input text, in my code it works, but the problem is that I can't find a way to retrieve the text in the input so i can save it later.

```
   function Edit(clickedButton){
        var getTR = clickedButton.closest('tr');
        var getLength = getTR.childElementCount;
        var getTds = getTR.querySelectorAll("td")

        for (i in getTds) {
            if(i < (getLength-1)) {
                getTds[i].innerHTML = "<input  type='text' value='"+getTds[i].innerHTML+"'>";
            }       
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you considered using the `contentEditable` attribute? It would save you replacing/updating text areas or inputs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable

Answer (score 1):

Get it by the id

```
document.getElementById('textbox_id').value
```

or

Get it by the class

`document.getElementsByClassName('class_name')[element_index].value`

or
get it by the tag name

```
document.getElementsByTagName('tag_name')[whole_number].value
```

Answer (score 0):

In your loop body add an event listener to the created input, for example bind to `blur` event to do something with the value once the input loses focus:

```
getTds[i].innerHTML = "<input  type='text' value='"+getTds[i].innerHTML+"'>";
getTds[i].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].addEventListener('blur', function(){
    console.log( this.value );
})
```

simplified example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lr08emod/